# PowerShell simple casting error

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, casting

```
 $mlField = [SPFieldMultiLineText]$field
```

I have a field, it is of type field but I want to cast it as SPFieldMultiLineText (I can confirm that this is a valid cast, I'm assuming my syntax is bad).

The error I'm getting:

**Unable to find type [SPFieldMultiLineText]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is loaded.**

This is a SharePoint Management Console so all relevant SharePoint assemblies are loaded - this is not the issue.

Any pointers in the right direction of making this cast without an error?

Thanks a lot.

EDIT: For a bit more context, this is ultimately what I'm trying to achieve:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pavankumar/archive/2008/11/17/how-to-change-a-multi-line-text-field-to-allow-unlimited-length-in-a-document-library.aspx

Comment: Have you tried with full type name: `$mlField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiLineText]$field` ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, please post as answer.

Comment: Cast comment to answer ;). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with full type name:

```
$mlField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldMultiLineText]$field
```